# What radix is this parseInt defaulting to?

Tags: javascript

I have read in many answers that under circumstances `radix` in `parseInt` default to `10`.

I don't understand though, why I get the output I do below, where the strings

```js
["1856", "1857", "1858"]
```

get parsed as:

```js
[1856, NaN, 1]
```

I've set up the example below to check how `parseInt` responds with different radix values. But none seem to match. What am I missing?

```js
const ids = ["1856", "1857", "1858"];

const parsed = Array.from(new Array(20).keys())
  .reduce((p, n) => ({
    ...p,
    [n]: ids.map(x => parseInt(x, n)),
  }))

console.log(ids.map(parseInt))
console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: Why would using `n` as the radix make *any* sense?

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: If you're going to have a "Run code snippet" button appear, you should make sure the code will actually run.

Comment: The problem is that when you pass `parseInt` directly as the `.map()` callback, it will be confused by the second parameter passed by `.map()`.  You have to wrap `parseInt()` in a function that ignores the second parameter.

Comment: "1857" is the second item in the array.  `parseInt("1857", 1)` yields `NaN`.